# how to verify a file's content is match to it's extension

Tags: java

My website allows [txt,csv,pdf,xlsx,xls,doc,docx,mp4...] files to be uploaded.
In order to prevent malicious attacks, I don’t want [exe,bat...] to upload files disguised as the above.
How can I verify that the content and extension of the uploaded file on my website are macthed.

Comment: I guess you will need different libraries to check each file type. Try to read a xls file with the proper library and if it doesn't fail the content is correct respect to its extension. Do the same for any other extension.

Comment: if malicious attacks is the only problem you have, you could use an online virus scanner api to scan files before transferring to your server

Answer (score 0):

On Linux/Unix systems there is the [`file` command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file) that checks a file and decides on the file type. In your case I'd try to reuse that logic rather than implementing something yourself.

I am not sure whether that command is available on Windows. You might want to get it through [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) or compile it yourself.